# How to achieve equal Sum Values horizontally and vertically in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working on this for a week now and still could not get the result I want. What I want is to have an equal result between the horizontal total and vertical total when summing up every columns in excel. Please consider this worksheet.
[image: actual worksheet]

Every TSalary values in each row is equal to each values in its row in Gross Pay Columns. The same thing also in TDeductions with the columns in Deductions. However, after summing up each row and getting its overall total in AD13 & AE13, I am not getting the same value with the total when summing up every columns in gross pay and deductions.

Answer (score 1):

In column AE you seem to have rounded each value to the nearer cent.  In cell N13 you have summed the unrounded values.

The 4 half-cents (in column N) that have thus been rounded to a full cent cause your total to be 2 cents higher than the total of the unrounded amounts.

You need to be consistent when applying roundings if you wish your totals to be consistent.

Comment: Yes I have rounded off to 2 places in the AD, AE and AF columns, since the "program" computed this way and it was accepted as the correct values. Can I achieve same results even if I still rounded off to 2 places. I've tried rounding off each columns but on no luck to get no variance.

Comment: @Nemesis Are the values in columns F:AA things that appear on employee pay slips?  If so, are the unrounded or rounded values of those items shown on the pay slips?  If the rounded values are shown, I would think it would be best if you rounded them in your spreadsheet too (i.e. round each cell in F9:AA12 to 2 decimal places to match their pay slips).  If you calculate the spreadsheet total as the rounded sum of the unrounded values, it won't match the total on the employee pay slip.  (Unless the pay slips show a total that doesn't match the individual figures !?!)

Comment: Actually what is being saved in the database is the unrounded values except for the TSalary, TDeduction and Net. What appears on payslip are rounded values for all the fields. Yeah I'll give a try to round off each columns in the spreadsheet. (Sometimes before, that's why I'm trying to fix it.)

Comment: @Nemesis - if you round everything in F9:AA12 it will match what is shown on the payslips, and the totals (in both directions) will automatically be rounded and therefore correct (and matching the payslips)